# Reload all clients pages on Service Worker skipWaiting call

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I want to be able to fully control my `Service Worker` verions,
I created signals and functions that allow me to `update` or `skipWaiting` an exsting `Service Worker` which works prefect!

```
self.addEventListener('install',event=>
    event.waitUntil(caches.open(version).then(cache=>
        cache.addAll([
            ...
        ]).then(_=>
            condition?
                self.skipWaiting():
            false
        )
    ))
)

self.addEventListener('activate',event=>
    event.waitUntil(clients.claim())
)
```

When I call `skipWaiting`, the client page is claimed by the new `Service Worker` as it supposed to,

**But I can't make it immediately reload from the new cache of the newly installed `Service Worker`**.

How can I `skipWaiting` and force all clients pages to reload themself from the cache of the newly installed `Service Worker`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet:

```js
// If service workers are supported...
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  // Check to see if the page is currently controlled.
  let isControlled = Boolean(navigator.serviceWorker.controller);

  // Listen for a change to the current controller...
  navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', () => {
    if (isControlled) {
      // ...and if the page was previosly controlled, reload the page.
      window.location.reload();
    } else {
      // ...otherwise, set the flag for future updates, but don't reload.
      isControlled = true;
    }
  });
}
```

I'd recommend basing this logic on the `controllerchange` event rather than some other approaches, like listening to the `statechange` of an installing/waiting service worker, since there's a small gap in time between when a service worker activates and when it takes control of existing clients. Waiting on each page for the `controller` to change will guarantee that the reload takes place under control of the updated service worker.

Using this code in conjunction with a service worker that calls `skipWaiting()` should give you the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: There are several problems with your code, if it's the first load (`installation`) and an update occur. if the listener is bind after the `controllerchange` fired.
The only way to 100% control it it's through the `service worker` interface, using clients array, the question is how do I detect `activation` as a result of `skipWaiting`?

Comment: I've updated the code to deal with the initial load not being controlled, but where you still want to trigger a reload when there's a SW update, which I see could only happen since you're also calling `clients.claim()` in your SW (otherwise the page loaded initially won't ever be controlled; only subsequent pages).

Comment: Given your code sample, if you're concerned about specifically detecting when you're calling `skipWaiting()`, I'd recommend just using a boolean flag initialized to `false` in the service worker's global scope, which you set to `true` if you call `skipWaiting()`. You can then check that flag in your `activate` handler. There's very little risk of the SW being killed in between calling `skipWating()` and the `activate` handler firing, so the global scope should stick around that long.

Comment: I thought about adding a boolean flag, but I wondered if there is a more elegant way to do it,
maybe the event returned by the `activation` return something that points out it came from `skipWaiting` or something alike.. there must be some indication, it seems like it is a basic need to be able to control updates on opened clients pages..